# Efficient way to group, sort and return first N results

Tags: algorithm, sorting, grouping, average

I have a stream (or long list of element, could be thousands or millions), and I have to return the first N groups (24 in my situation) sorted by the average of the group. So items are in the form:

```
{groupId: 1, value: 10}, {groupId: 2, value: 4}, {groupId: 1: value: 2}
```

and form groups:

```
{groupId: 1, average: 6}, {groupId: 2: average}
```

Clearly the naive solution is to iterate, group, sort groups by average and return the first 24 groups. Any idea for an high performance solution that can deal with millions of items?

Comment: If you want to sort the groups by their average, there is no way around iterating the entire list. But even for "millions", this should not be much of a problem.

Comment: Hmm. You didn't tell what kind of data is that. Maybe you can use a micro-batching app like Apache Spark or Apache Storm

Comment: @CaptainFogetti this data comes from Lucene index, and I am trying to implement a Lucene Collector for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot escape iterating over the whole list to get each and every member of a given group. Once you have each group available with its mean, you can do the following:

1. Take the *N* first groups into a vector/array.
2. Make a heap out of that array such that the top of the heap is the group with the maximum average.
3. For each remaining group, compare it with the top of the heap:

   - If the current group is greater than the top of the heap, discard it
   - If it is smaller, pop the top of the heap and insert the current group

At the end you have all the *N* first groups in a heap. You can get them in order by applying the last step of a heap sort and reverse the container you obtain (because the heap is a max-heap).

**Overall complexity:** (where *K* is the total number of groups and *N* defined above)

> *O(N + (K-N).ln(N) + N.ln(N)* = *O(N + K.ln(N))*

- The term *N* comes from taking the first *N* groups and making the initial max-heap.
- The term *(K-N).ln(N)* comes from the (delete top / insert current group) pairs of operations (at most *K - N* of them).
- The last term (*N.ln(N)*) is for the sorting of the final heap.

Comment: thanks a lot. This is more or less what Solr is doing to sort grouped results, but they use the max function instead of average. Do you know if these kind of sorting (sort for first N elements) have a name in the algorithm field?

Comment: @agori Not that I know of, but this problem is well known. There is even a better solution that you can find in "Cracking the coding interview" IIRC.

Comment: I have used the priority queue implemented by Guava:

`MinMaxPriorityQueue.orderedBy(new MyComparator())        .maximumSize(groupOffset + this.topNGroups).create();`

Answer (score 1):

Just keep for every group two values - sum of values for that group and counter. In the end divide sum by counter to get average for this group.

You cannot keep info for limited number of groups because any group might become a leader at some moment.